# confusion matrix not displayed in google cloud automl vision

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, automl, google-cloud-automl

I'm not observing the confusion matrix in the "EVALUATE" tab of the web UI when following the basic quickstart:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/quickstart?refresh=1

The confusion matrix should be displayed according to this documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/evaluate

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this happens because multi-label classification is enabled during importing of the image dataset. Since multiple labels can correspond to each image, hence the confusion matrix is not well-defined.